# Installing YUM in Ubuntu 20.04 to run CentOS LXC Containers

Tags: package-management, lxc, yum

I was able to install Yum in Ubuntu 18.04 but I can't install it anymore in Ubuntu 20.04. So, when I try to run a CentOS LXC container in my Ubuntu I get an error like this one:

```
# lxc-create -n centos7 -t centos -- -R 7
Host CPE ID from /etc/os-release: 
'yum' command is missing
lxc-create: centos7: lxccontainer.c: create_run_template: 1626 Failed to create container from template
lxc-create: centos7: tools/lxc_create.c: main: 319 Failed to create container centos7
```

I've tryed to download the latest yum.deb packages from several sites (pkgs.org, etc.) but there is no way to satisfy the package dependencies (i.e python-lzma).

So, the question is either of these: how do I install YUM in Ubuntu 20.04 or how do I run a CentOS container using LXC in Ubuntu 20.04?. Previous LTS versions of Ubuntu worked great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, definitely it is not an optimal solution, but it is the only one I found.

As I'm using Dockers quite often, I have docker installed and I've created a new /usr/bin/yum file (executable) with this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker run --rm -v /var/cache:/var/cache roboxes/centos8 bin/yum $*
```

So when yum is executed, my own docker version of "yum" runs. It is not a nice solution, but at least it does the job.

I've previously run, though this is not mandatory.

```
docker pull roboxes/centos8
```

No RPM package is needed either.

No CentOS 8 is supported in this LXC version (because of the lxc-centos template). It is not optimal, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
lxc-create --name centos7 --template=download -- --dist=centos --release=7 --arch=amd64
```

works fine on ubuntu20

Answer (score 0):

install yum :

```bsh
apt install yum
```

after that Try this command:

```bsh
lxc-create -t centos -n client11  

ou 

/usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-centos -n centos01 -R 7
```

Comment: `yum` was removed starting in Ubuntu 20 mainline repos (it was available in 18)